# Mobac .mbtiles files get a no tile_data error

Tags: mbtiles, mobile-atlas-creator

The symptom of my problems is that when my ios code tries to access the map I get a tile_data error. The maps appear to generate normally.

I have a sample mobac created mbtiles file and it works in xcode like it should.

I have created my own mobac maps and they

- preview in finder and xcode ok
- appear to have valid data and structure when opened by a sqlite utility app

however they

- throw the no tile_data error when the simulator is run
- come up as blank previews in MapTiler (from maptiler.com)

FWIW I get the same problem with maps produced on win7 and my mac.

I have tried using mobac versions 1.9, 1.9.11 and 1.9.16 as well as 2A1

I got tripped up briefly by my jdk version but I've got that straight. I can't see what else I need to do. If there's an alternate tool that's newbie friendly let me know.

I've created really detailed maps in QGIS with filters and styles and layers. I want to be able to use it as an alternate source to OpenStreetMap but if I can't even get a basic map to generate I'm a bit concerned!

Comment: In which table are you searching for the `tile_data` column? Which 'MapTiler` are you using? A google Search gives links to atleast 3 different softwares called 'MapTiler'

Comment: Here is a sample mbtiles files, which I have generated with MAC, and tested with many other softwares: https://www.dropbox.com/s/fbadt8lb5ejubg8/Sample.mbtiles Does it work for you?

Comment: That's curious Devdatta. The plugin developer's sample mbtiles file shows the map with no tile_data errors. Your sample shows in the simulator but does generate the errors some of the time. It opens in the maptiler.com app. 

I'm not overly worried about the errors if I can get my map to show.

The query that gets run is

`select tile_data from tiles where zoom_level = ? and tile_column = ? and tile_row = ?"`

and then the error comes when xcode does a sqlite3_column_type

Comment: Can you share a sample mbtile file (maybe with just a couple of zoom levels, like I have shared) created with MAC which shows the issue that you are facing?

Comment: I sure can.
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=71DA6DFBE22FBAB0!16629&authkey=!ALahNkAbowfmCf4&ithint=file%2cmbtiles 
https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=71DA6DFBE22FBAB0!17391&authkey=!ALggJ7s0bU_Dq9o&ithint=file%2cmbtiles
I may have narrowed it down to a call for tiles at a zoom level that isn't included and the problem is therefore in the error handling and not the file. I haven't got that confirmed though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the mbtiles flies that you have sent. The files are proper, except the metdata table being empty in 'RarotongaMap.mbtiles' file.

As you have found out, the errors are occurring when your software is trying to search for tiles which do not exist in the database. You should note that nowhere does the MBtiles Spec mention that all the tiles for all zoom level should exist in the database.

Usually the Database will contain tiles only for the area that you are interested in, at the zoom levels that you specify. It is upto you, how you handle the missing tiles. In this case as you have found out, the errors are not being handled properly.

Another case for an empty map can be when you have set a big bound in the metadata table, but you do not have tiles for higher zoom levels. For Example in your 'riverhead.mbtiles' database, your bounds are `174.474,-36.792,174.683,0.000`, but you have tiles only from zoom level 12. This Big extent will be covered by something like Zoom level 4, and since you don't have tiles at this zoom level, the map will be empty.